# How to add a condition to a generic case_when statement including the glue function?

Tags: r, case, r-glue

I have two data frames (df1 and df2) as you can see in the tables below. Based on the conditions in df1, I need to check the values in df2. The expected output is also presented.
The condition is based on the columns `dep` and `value` in `df1` checked in `df2` against the the variables taken from the column `var` in `df1`. Please see the following examples:

For instance, based on row 1 in df1, we judge whether the values in column A in df2 are TRUE or FALSE.

1. `if E == 1, A == TRUE`
2. `if E != 1`, we need to check the following conditions:

   `- if A == NA, A == TRUE`

   `- if A == any values other than NA, A == FALSE`
3. `If A and E are both NAs, A == TRUE`

Here is the code that works for the first two conditions, my question is how to add the third condition:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
library(glue)
rules_1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~var, ~value,    ~dep,
  "A",   "==1",    "E", 
  "B",   "==1",    "E", 
  "C",   "!=0",    "A", 
  "D",   "==2",    "G", 
  "E",      NA,     NA, 
  "F",      NA,     NA, 
  "G",    "%in% c('b','d')",     "F",
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ID = c("1q", "2d", "4f", "3g", "8j", "5g", "9l"),
  B = c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L),
  G = c(3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA),
  A = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA),
  C = c(NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L),
  D = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L),
  E = c(2L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 3L, 1L),
  F = letters[1:7]
)

# And for variables that have NA values in df1, we do not need to do anything. 

(rules_2 <- filter(rules_1,
                   !is.na(dep)))

# rules from data
(rules_3 <- mutate(rules_2,
                   rule = glue("case_when({dep}{value}~TRUE,is.na({var})~TRUE,TRUE ~ FALSE)")))

(mutators <- rules_3$rule)
names(mutators) <- rules_3$var

(parsed_mutators <- rlang::parse_exprs(mutators))

mutate(df2,
       !!!parsed_mutators)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extend the case_when logic

```
case_when( {dep}{value}~TRUE,
           is.na({dep}) & is.na({var}) ~ TRUE,
           is.na({var})~TRUE,
           TRUE ~ FALSE)
```

Comment: can you not look at your data and make an example out of it that exemplifies your problem ?

Comment: 2 things; I dont see the value of glue::double_quote, but just so long as when you establish the rules , i.e. rule2 you probably backquote the non-standard variable names. here you simply have a typo on DEELN#CHIANTI as you have a starting backtick but not an ending one